# Combining ECDSA keys

Tags: c++, openssl, addition, ecdsa, modular-arithmetic

How can I combine two ECDSA private/public keypairs into one? I know it's done with modular addition in openssl, I just don't understand how that works. Can anyone explain that to me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that by adding two private keys

```
privkey = privateA + privateB (mod order)
```

or, in OpenSSL code:

```
BN_mod_add_quick(privkey, privateA, privateB, order);
```

Here `order` is the smallest number where `order = s - j`, such that `sP = jP` for a point P on the elliptic curve. The public key of your new private key is `pubkey = privkey * G`, or:

```
EC_POINT_mul(group, pubkey, privkey, NULL, NULL, ctx);
```

The values of `order` and generator point `G` are curve parameters and are set when creating and setting `group`(an EC_GROUP object).

Answer (score 0):

ECDSA private key - is just a number, order of base point.
You can just add two private keys (i.e. numbers), reducing sum modulo base point order, and exponentiating the base point to this order.
But why should you need this?

Comment: For split-key zero-trust generation of keys. privateA + privateB == publicA + publicB. I dont follow your answer, though. What do you mean order of base point?

Comment: Order of base point is, hmm, just order of base point :) Or, order of the curve, order of the group of elliptic curve points, dunno what othar synonyms it have. Base point G, added to itself N times (where N is order), will produce the same point G.